# Including Room-library increases app download size (~10mb)

Tags: android, android-room

In short: How to minify Room-library? Maybe with a proguard-file??

As a background then I switched my project to use Room-library and my refactoring works fine, but for my "shock" the Room-library have increased my app download size by c.10mb (from 5mb to 15mb).

I have looked into generated APK and the 10mb-reason seems to be the ICU-stuff (I am saving just primitive types to Room and not using localization/unicode in my APP). So can I just somehow leave out ICU-part?

Edit (More details): I am able to reproduce my "issue" with following steps:

1. Open Android Studio (I have 3.5.3)
2. Create a new project (with Empty Acitivity and min API22)
3. Generate a build (buildtool version 29.0.2)

   - In my case the APK size is 1.6mb and download size is 1.3m ("Build->Analyze APK..")
4. Add Room-library to project:

> 

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.2'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.2'
```

(4.5 I also need to add a following compile option:)

```
android {  
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

5. Generate a build

   - APK size 17.7mb and download size 16.7mb

About "ICU-stuff" then my apologies about fuzzy terms. I have used it because I am not sure about the problem. Nevertheless I have used "ICU-stuf", because I can see big files under ICU-directory (see picture below). 
[image]

Comment: Room, on its own, does not add 10MB to an APK. For example, I am looking right now at a 1.6MB APK that is just Room examples. What is "the ICU-stuff"? How have you determined that this is "the 10mb-reason"? What are you including in your `dependencies` list in the module's `build.gradle` file?

Comment: I have updated my question with more details. I can paste more info if it is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove:

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.2'
```

Comment: Because it's only needed at compile, not runtime?

Comment: Test it, but my app crashes (top error):

E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com...

Comment: I will just share this then I did an uninstall and install and then the app started to work. I got some error after I did remove room-compiler dependency. But removing room-compiler reduced my app size to 5mb. (Error in my comment above was about proguard file s I just disabled it for now)